# dynamic elements and click events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I'm generating elements from a list and each of these will have a click event.
This is all in the same partial view that gets refreshed every X seconds elapsed.

The first initial load doesn't work. Every auto refresh of the partial after works fine.

all (document).ready events fire.

Other code outside of the click events fire just fine.

Loop in view

```
<div id="@overview.GroupType.Name" class="tile @overview.AlertType.MetroBG ui-widget-content draggable" data-role="tile" style="z-index: 2;">
    <div class="tile-content iconic" style="z-index: 2;">
        <span class="icon @overview.AlertType.MetroImage @overview.AlertType.MetroFG"></span>
        <span class="tile-badge @overview.AlertType.MetroBadgeBG @overview.AlertType.MetroBadgeFG">@overview.BadgeCount.ToString()</span>
        <span class="tile-label no-padding fg-white">@overview.GroupType.Description</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

loop in script section of (document).ready generates the following

```
$('#@overview.GroupType.Name').on("click", function () {
    alert('click');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("LoadDetail", "Home")',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { 'groupName': '@overview.GroupType.Name' },
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#monitorDetail").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
        }
        })
    });
```

I read a few posts saying you have to use .on("click" ...) so I'm not sure what else to look into.

Comment: You should call it after the partilview load, using Success function.

Comment: @Fals since the controller is passing the model needed to the view, would I have to call another view with the same model that generates the click events after the first view is loaded? Since all the code is in the same view and is getting auto refreshed, why does this work on the second try and not the first initial load?

Comment: You are rendering stuff after the main view loads. You must call the function that bind anything to the new DOM after you render each partial view

Comment: @Tsukasa is that div the dynamic element?

Comment: @Fals the model passed by the controller to the partial view contains the data to generate the code. Are you saying that from the main view after loading the partial in question I need to then generate the jQuery events? This would mean I need to have my main view hold the model for the partial to load the events after?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', '#@overview.GroupType.Name', function(){
    // do stuff here
});
```

You could replace the `body` selector with the non-dynamic parent of your dynamic div . I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I got from your question, but still a bit confusing:

1) You are loading something dynamically using ajax into the main view every  5s.

2) When this happens you need to bind events to something inside this dynamic content.

3) It's not working (dahh for sure not, you asked us).

**Solution:**

You must bind any event after the Partial Refresh, at the success method. Why? Because you have changed the DOM and the first `$('document').ready` did't find out this content loaded with ajax at the first time.

```
$('#@overview.GroupType.Name').on("click", function () {
    alert('click');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("LoadDetail", "Home")',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { 'groupName': '@overview.GroupType.Name' },
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#monitorDetail").html(data);
        //Bind the events to for anything after loading the content
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
        }
        })
    });
```

And this script above will work only if the script is inside the main view, because It's need Razor Server Render to build the id `'#@overview.GroupType.Name'`. You can't have dynamic script at the partial. Ajax will not execute this scripts.

Comment: Ok so that event lives in the partial, I have to move it into the main for it to work correctly?

Comment: yes! Any JavaScript should stay inside the main view or will not exec